# Using a C function in Python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes

I've tried all the solutions mentioned on the internet so far nothing worked for me.

I have a python code, to speed it up, I want that my code runs the heavy calculations in a C function.
I already wrote this C function.

Then, to share the library, I did this in the terminal :

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-install_name,testlib.so -o testlib.so -fPIC myModule.c
```

which returns no error. The problem; comes when i try to launch the C function in python. Let's consider the following simple function in C :

```
int multiplier(int a, int b)
{

int lol = 0;

lol = a*b;

return lol;
}
```

I launch python3 (3.5.2), and then :

```
import ctypes
zelib = ctypes.CDLL("/Users/longeard/Desktop/Codes/DraII/testlib.so",ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
```

The library should be ready to use in python by doing :

```
res = zelib.multiplier(2,3)
```

When doing that, it works and python returns

```
6
```

Problem is, that the function i want to use ( the multiplier function I use is just for the example ) is supposed to take floats as input and return a float. But if I now consider the same multiplier function as before but with float :

```
float multiplier(float a, float b)
{

float lol = 0.0;

lol = a*b;

return lol;
}
```

I recompile using gcc, I reimport ctypes and re-do ctypes.CDLL, and I do in python3 :

```
zelib.multiplier(ctypes.c_float(2),ctypes.c_float(3))
```

(the types.c_float are here to convert the 2 in python into a float in C ), python will return :

```
2
```

This is weird because if I add a printf within the function to print lol, python will print :

```
  6.0
```

but still return 2, or 18 sometimes. Even though I printf and return the same variable "lol".

I tried a lot of things, and none of it worked. Do somebody have a idea please ? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @falsetru's answer is the better way of doing it an alternative is to simply write your C function to use doubles.

Floats are automatically promoted to double when  calling a function without a parameter list.

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify `restype`, `argtypes` of the function:

```
zelib = ctypes.CDLL('...')
zelib.multiplier.restype = ctypes.c_float   # return type
zelib.multiplier.argtypes = [ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_float]  # argument types
```

According to [Specifying the required argument types (function prototypes)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes):

> It is possible to specify the required argument types of functions exported from DLLs by setting the `argtypes` attribute.

and [Return types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#return-types) in [`ctypes` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html):

> By default functions are assumed to return the C int type. Other return types can be specified by setting the `restype` attribute of the function object.

---

```
# without specifying types
>>> import ctypes
>>> zelib = ctypes.CDLL('testlib.so')
>>> zelib.multiplier(2, 3)
0

# specifying types
>>> zelib.multiplier.restype = ctypes.c_float
>>> zelib.multiplier.argtypes = [ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_float]
>>> zelib.multiplier(2, 3)
6.0
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm ! I actually tried that several times yesterday, for some reason it didn't work, but now it does.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment .... DO you happen to know how to pass numpy float array as an input in this case ? And return an array in the C function as well ? Thank you.

Comment: @Nicano, Check this out: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html  If you have more question, please post it as another question.